# ASP.NET MVC3 EditorTemplates Loaded via Ajax w/o duplicating jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, mvc-editor-templates

I'm using EditorTemplates for things like DateTime, Colors, etc. My forms, which may contain quite a bit of these templates, are primarily loaded via Ajax as a partial view.

Rather than have a bunch of jQuery initialization scripts at the bottom of each editor template, is there a conceptual way to do it only once per response? Lets say the you have 10 date time pickers, on one form, it would be really silly to pass down the same initialization code 10 times.

Placing the initialization script on the main form with the 10 date pickers would be efficient (certainly doesn't do much to keep code isolated to the datetime editor template), but then there's other cases where you may just want to have one date time picker on a different form or two or three, and now you're duplicating those scripts across multiple views in your code.

So how can I still leverage editor templates the right way here? I think I'm looking for something like --

```
EnsureThisScriptIsOutputOncePerThisResponse(<script>$('.datepicker').datepicker("insert lengthy config here");</script>)
```

to add to the bottom of the editor template that works with partial views rendered via AJAX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing we did on our project was to have a startup.js file that extends the unobtrusive javascript pattern by utilizing data attributes for configuring things like that.  An example for ours is buttons.  Let's say I had the following html:

```
<input type='submit' data-button=true data-button-icon='ui-icon-check' value='approve' />
```

the startup file looks for buttons something like this:

```
function initializeButtons() {
    $("*[data-button=true]").each(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var initialized = $this.data('button-init');
        if (!initialized) {
            var options = {
                disabled: $this.data('button-disabled'),
                text: $this.data('button-text'),
                icons: {
                    primary: $this.data('button-icon-primary') || $this.data('button-icon'),
                    secondary: $this.data('button-icon-secondary')
                }
            };
            $this.button(options);
            $this.data('button-init', true);
        }
    });
}

$(document).ready(initializeButtons).ajaxSuccess(initializeButtons)
```

This makes common jQuery UI initialization code much easier to manage, and we created HtmlHelper extensions to easily fill in the data attributes for the stuff we need/use.

Comment: thanks. Then i take it for something rendered via ajax you would then have to call initializebuttons again with a simple <script>initializebuttons()</script> at the bottom of the view?

Comment: nope...  the `$(document).ready(initializeButtons).ajaxSuccess(initializeButtons)` calls `initializeButtons` on document ready **and** ajax success.

Comment: Interesting. I like this. Prior to your initial response I started going down the path of moving everything to a .js file, and then just call a function at the end of each partial view passing in a selector to initialize the item. Is there any performance issues with calling this function (and potentially 10 others for different types of editors/ui objects) after each ajax call?

Comment: I suppose there is the potential for performance issues... although after over a year of using this technique with a wide range of applications, I haven't noticed any.

It's faster than a Viking longship on its way to pillage, IMO

Answer (score 2):

> So how can I still leverage editor templates the right way here? I
>   think I'm looking for something like --
>   EnsureThisScriptIsOutputOncePerThisResponse() to add to the bottom of
>   the editor template.

Using [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/). This is the library that allows you to reference scripts and stylesheets from anywhere - even from partial views. Then it ensures script reference order and renders scripts ensuring this script and its references output only once and generally in single place in response.

**Update:**

Referencing scripts for ajax can be done as follows

In datepicker editor template - EditorTemplates/DateTime.cshtml

```
@model DateTime?
@{
    Bundles.ReferenceScript("path to datepicker script. Script may reference jquery ui in its turn");
} 
//datepicker
```

And in datepicker container form, directly render scripts. If not ajax, this would have been done in Layout page

```
@model ViewModelModelWithTenDates
@Bundles.RenderScripts() //will output distinc script references in order

//10 datepickers
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstDate)
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm not convinced that Cassette will work with partial views rendered via Ajax.

Comment: It surely works. I did exactly that today :). What is result of ajax? It's the piece of html, which can contain script tags, and those scripts will be executed. See my update

Answer (score 1):

You can use `livequery` plugin to put add the initialization code into an external .js file and include the file in your _Layout.cshtml.

```
$(".datepicker").livequery(function(){
    $(this).datepicker("insert lengthy config here");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I use an init attribute om the stuff that needs some script run:

```
<input type="text" id="id" init="datepicker makereadonly" />
```

This indicates that two functions have to be run. Running them is done in the Ajax-complete which is defined in an external file, notice that once an item is initialized the initialized attribute is set. This way no script exists in your partial views.

```
var initFunctions = initFunctions || {};

initFunctions.datepicker = function(item) {
    $(item).datepicker();
};

initFunctions.readonly = function(item) {
    $(item).attr("disabled", "disabled");
};

$('body').ajaxComplete(function (e, xhr, settings) {
  var itemFunction = function (item) {
     var $this = $(item);
     var attr = $this.attr("init");
     var functions = attr.split(" ");
     for (var i = 0; i < functions.length; i++) {
        var funcName = functions[i];
        var func = initFunctions[funcName];
        if (func != undefined)
           func($this);
     }
     $this.attr("initialized", "");
  };

  items = $("[init]:not([initialized])");
  items.each(function (index, item) { itemFunction(item); });
});
```